# Simplification of fractions of unit symbols: wrong results

Tags: python, list, algorithm, function, math

I'm writing a function that simplifies fractions with symbols (like "kg") without numbers (coefficients).

The function takes two arguments: the first list has all the units referred to in the numerator, the second lists the units referred to in the denominator.

I think I've already completed most of the function, but I don't understand why it doesn't pass some of the tests.

For example, when the denominator and the numerator are equal it is not returning `(['1'], ['1'])` as expected, and another example is when the function in one for the tests returns `(['1', '1', 's'], ['s'])` instead of `(['1'], ['1'])`.

My code:

```
def canonical(unit):
    numerador = unit[0]
    denominador = unit[1]
    numerador.sort()
    denominador.sort()
    
    lstNumerador = numerador
    lstDenominador = denominador
    
    for i in numerador:
        for j in denominador:
            if i == j:
                lstNumerador.remove(i)
                lstDenominador.remove(j)
                
    
    if lstNumerador.count('1') > 0:
        lstNumerador.remove('1')
        
    if lstDenominador.count('1') > 0:
        lstDenominador.remove('1')
        
    if len(lstNumerador) == 0:
        lstNumerador.append('1')
        
    if len(lstDenominador) == 0:
        lstDenominador.append('1')
        
    unit = (lstNumerador, lstDenominador)
    return unit

# What I expect

unit = (['kg', 'm', 'm', 's'], ['m', 's', 's'])
print(canonical(unit))
#(['kg', 'm'], ['s'])
unit = (['kg', 'm', 'm', 's'], ['s', 'm', 'm', 'kg'])
print(canonical(unit))
#(['1'], ['1'])
unit = (['s', 'kg', 'm', '1'], ['1', '1'])
print(canonical(unit))
#(['kg', 'm', 's'], ['1'])
unit = (['1', 'm', 's', '1', '1'], ['m', 's'])
print(canonical(unit))
#(['1'], ['1'])
unit = (['kg', 'm', 'm'], ['kg', 'm', 'm'])
print(canonical(unit))
#(['1'], ['1'])

# What I received instead

(['kg', 'm'], ['s'])
(['m', 's'], ['m', 's'])
(['kg', 'm', 's'], ['1'])
(['1', '1', 's'], ['s'])
(['m'], ['m'])
```

Comment: You are modifying a List whilst iterating over it. This is a well-known error. Because the loop 'remembers' the position in the List then following access is compromised when elements are removed.

Comment: so how can i fix it? can you explain to me?

Comment: Instead of modifying the List  being iterated build  a new one with the elements you DO want and then at the end this becomes the result. `mylist.append('c')` adds the character 'c' to a List which can be originally created as an empty List using `mylist = []`

Comment: Or have another List originally with the same content and remove from that.

Comment: I just did what you said, and still the same error :(

Comment: Please update your code so it can be seen.

Comment: ok, already edited

Comment: *"I think you've already done most of the function"*: who are you referring to with "you"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you call `remove` on a list that you are iterating. That is rarely a good idea, because it "pulls the rug" under the iterator, which thereby may *skip* some values.

Secondly, that nested loop is generally not efficient. This can better be done with dictionaries.

This code challenge is actually an ideal candidate for [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dictionaries. Besides that the constructor creates a dictionary with a count per element, it also allows subtraction of two such Counter objects, and negation of a Counter object with the unary operator. You can easily get the individual (repeated) elements again with the `elements` method. All this is very handy to achieve the desired result in an efficient way.

Here is how that would look:

```
from collections import Counter

def canonical(unit):
    diff = Counter(unit[0])
    diff.subtract(unit[1])  # May produce negative frequencies
    del diff["1"]  # NB: Counter objects don't raise "key error"
    return list(diff.elements()) or ["1"], list((-diff).elements()) or ["1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: i left denominator empty instead of adding one to it

```
def canonical(unit):
    numerador = sorted([i for i in unit[0] if i!='1'])
    denominador = sorted([i for i in unit[1] if i!='1'])


    numCount= {i : numerador.count(i)-denominador.count(i) for i in set(numerador +denominador)}
    
    numerador=[]
    denominador= []

    for num,count in numCount.items():
        if count>0:
            numerador+=[num]*count
        elif count<0:
            denominador+= [num]*-count

    if len(numerador) == 0:
        numerador=['1']
    if len(denominador) == 0:
        denominador=['1']
    
    return (numerador, denominador)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !! but it doesn't work... the tests do not match the output of the function

Comment: I know you can add if len(denominador) == 0:denominador=['1']   before return

Comment: I still don't think it works but thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

See copy below. I created a deepcopy of your unit so it is impregnable to iterate/remove and also corrected the logic which was wrong in a few places. This gives the output you expect.

```
import copy

def canonical(unit):
    numerador = unit[0]
    denominador = unit[1]
    numerador.sort()
    denominador.sort()
    
    lstNumerador = copy.deepcopy(numerador)
    lstDenominador = copy.deepcopy(denominador)
    
    for i in numerador:
        for j in denominador:
            if (i in lstNumerador) and (i in lstDenominador):
                    lstNumerador.remove(i)
                    lstDenominador.remove(i)
                
    
    while lstNumerador.count('1') > 1:
        lstNumerador.remove('1')
        
    while lstDenominador.count('1') > 1:
        lstDenominador.remove('1')
        
    if len(lstNumerador) == 0:
        lstNumerador.append('1')
        
    if len(lstDenominador) == 0:
        lstDenominador.append('1')
        
    unit = (lstNumerador, lstDenominador)
    return unit

unit1 = (['kg', 'm', 'm', 's'], ['m', 's', 's'])

unit2 = (['kg', 'm', 'm', 's'], ['s', 'm', 'm', 'kg'])

unit3 = (['s', 'kg', 'm', '1'], ['1', '1'])

unit4 = (['1', 'm', 's', '1', '1'], ['m', 's'])

unit5 = (['kg', 'm', 'm'], ['kg', 'm', 'm'])

units = [unit1, unit2, unit3, unit4, unit5]

for entry in units:
    print(canonical(entry))
```

output:

```
(['kg', 'm'], ['s'])
(['1'], ['1'])
(['kg', 'm', 's'], ['1'])
(['1'], ['1'])
(['1'], ['1'])
```